# Pushing Nagios notifications to Growl 1.2.2 - Growl not listening

Tags: nagios, growl

First time poster so please let me know if I leave anything out!

I am trying to get Nagios to push notifications to growl on a client machine, but am not having much luck with getting growl to register the application.

I am using a perl script that I found [here](http://gothamlabs.org/?p=90) with growl version 1.2.2. The notifications are being sent to the appropriate address and I was able to capture them in WireShark and they look correctly formed.

The problem is that Growl is not listening for UDP port 9887 (it is listening on TCP 23052, but that is not what that version supports for network notifications) and I can't seem to make it. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

It appears to not be a problem unique to me per [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/growldiscuss/_R9PSytxGIY) forum post, but a solution was never really posted...

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

Any general advice at all... from anyone :(

Comment: Growl for Windows or Mac?